# Redirect rows that fail to parse in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a fairly simple data flow where I'm importing from a flat file, doing some simple transforms, and inserting into a database table. My problem is that when the vendor puts in data that doesn't conform to their spec in one row (i.e. they said a column would be a numeric(3,2) put put in 500000), the whole file fails rather than just that one row. Ideally, I'd like to redirect the bad row(s), untouched, to a flat file, but putting them into an "error table" would work as well. How do I go about redirecting the unparsable data?

Comment: You use the error output stream from the first task that assigns columns to the imported data.

Comment: While inserting the data to the destination, you can change the method to "OpenRowset" only. By default, its "OpenRowset with fastload". This way, you will be able to single out only the bad row and not the entire batch/file. Let us know if that helps.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: The problem that I'm having with that approach is that it's the flat file data source that's throwing the error. The error output from that doesn't resemble the data row.

Comment: @rvphx: The data flow doesn't make it that far: it's failing in the flat file data source.

Comment: You need to edit the Flat File Source definition, and add Error Output definitions that tell it to "Redirect Row" for conversion errors on each column.  This should then embed the failed row's data into the error output row.

Comment: How do you redirect (failed) rows and also fail component/package?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the failed rows from the fast loading destination to a non-fast loading. Records that fail at that second destination can be redirected and investigated further.

The section 'Handling Failed Inserts when using Fast Load' in the following blog post explains this design pattern: http://www.mattmasson.com/2011/12/design-pattern-avoiding-transactions/

Answer (score 0):

Add to the the Flatfile source a Flatfile destination. all bad data will be sent there and the process wont fail. Also remember to redirect the rows and not keep it on fail. will also have to create a normal .txt file to map to the flatfile destination (same as with flatfile source)